# Front-end unable to read component's code between { }

Tags: component, front-end

Using Saxum Picker, I'm trying to insert a Paypal Form in the Component's Description Field, but whenever I insert code between { }, it saves on backend, but it doesn't show properly on front-end.

**- Sourcerer Extension:**

```
{source}[[form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top"]]{/source}
```

**Back-end:** Code saved.
**Front-end:** Inspect Page - Code Missing.

^ This extension was used in other components of the website with the same form, and it's working, except for this component (Saxum Picker).

**- Custom Html Advanced Extension:**

```
{loadposition MyPaypalCode}
```

**Back-end:** Code saved.
**Front-end:** Appears as text: "{loadposition MyPaypalCode}"

Comment: I don't know this component but Maybe the component does not support content plugins or its support is disabled.

Comment: See if you can find any setting in your component that says "Prepare code" or "Run content plugins" or similar. It sounds like your component isn't rendering the content propperly.

Comment: Are you putting the markup in code view? This type of syntax is intended to be inserted via the WYSIWYG editor.

Comment: Just spoke with Component's developer. It seems the whole component is a form, so I can't create a form inside of a form. I will just make an iframe. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Saxum Picker, so this is a bit of a shot in the dark, but will shed some light on how the mechanism works so that you have somewhere to look.

If you look at `plugins\content\loadmodule\loadmodule.php`, you'll see a function called `onContentPrepare()`.  *This* is where the "magic" of substituting something within the braces occurs *for content* (its a "content" plugin).

You say that this isn't occurring in "a Component's Description Field".  The substitution of (loadposition...} works on *Content* text (introtext and fulltext), not just any description in the database.

So, in short, Saxum Picker will have to do the substitution that Joomla does with content with that plugin.

Comment: Just spoke with Component's developer. It seems the whole component is a form, so I can't create a form inside of a form. I will just make an iframe. Thanks!